# Difference between yield self and yield?

Tags: ruby, yield, self

Could anyone please help me to understand the difference between "yield self" and "yield"?

```
class YieldFirstLast
    attr_accessor :first, :last

    def initialize(first = nil, last = nil)
        @first = first
        @last = last
        yield self if block_given?
    end

    def hello
        puts "#{@first} #{@last} says hello!"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 21):

In the case of `yield self`, `self` is the argument passed to the block.  With simply `yield`, no argument is passed.  `self` is not special here, anything could be yielded, e.g.

```
class Foo
  def a() yield self end
  def b() yield end
  def c() yield "Bar" end
  def d() yield 1, 2, "scuba" end
  def to_s() "A!" end
end

Foo.new.a {|x| puts x } #=> A!
Foo.new.b {|x| puts x } #=> (a blank line, nil was yielded)
Foo.new.c {|x| puts x } #=> Bar
Foo.new.d {|x, y, z| puts z } #=> scuba
```

Comment: what if there is more than one argument passed to the block? Is Self an array of them ?

Comment: `self` is a reference to the instance, but like I said, nothing special here.  Essentially think of yield as a method that takes any arguments and passes them to the block.  See the edit for multiple arguments.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Let me check my understanding, so when we use self, x is assigned as current objects reference. But if we don't use self, x is not assigned to any object.

Comment: Yes, it might be helpful to think the block as a method, and `yield` as the invocation of that method. The block `{|x, y| x + y }` is analagous to `def fn(x, y) x + y end`.  If you invoked `fn` with no arguments, `fn()`, you would expect `x` to be undefined in the method body, yes?

Answer (score 5):

`yield self` enters block, associated with method call, passing current object as argument to the block, plain `yield` just enters the block without passing any arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Think of `yield` as invoking your block and `yield self` is invoking your block with the current instance as the parameter.